# Create a pdf from an image list

Tags: python, image, pdf

I am developing a program in python to produce raffle tickets. The program creates as many tickets as required from a reference image by modifying only the ticket number. I have a list of images with potentially several hundred items. I would like to resize my images and save them in a pdf to allow printing. The user has to choose the number of tickets per row and per column on an A4 page

```
PIL_img_list = [...]
nbr_per_line = input("Number of ticket per line")
nbr_per_column = input("Number of ticket per column")
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: The first part (creation of the images) is already done

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer

You can simply add the `Image` to a `Document` (use absolute positioning), and then add a `Paragraph`  of text (containing the raffle number) at the position you want to have it.

```py
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import Image
from borb.pdf import Paragraph
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.pdf.canvas.geometry.rectangle import Rectangle

from decimal import Decimal

# create empty document
doc: Document = Document()

# add empty page
pge: Page = Page()
doc.add_page(pge)

# define a Rectangle on which we want to draw content
# fmt: off
r: Rectangle = Rectangle(
    Decimal(59),                # x: 0 + page_margin
    Decimal(848 - 84 - 100),    # y: page_height - page_margin - height_of_textbox
    Decimal(595 - 59 * 2),      # width: page_width - 2 * page_margin
    Decimal(100),               # height
)
# fmt: on

# add Image
Image("path_to_image.png", 
      width=Decimal(100), 
      height=Decimal(100)).paint(pge, r)

# add Paragraph
Paragraph("00001").paint(pge, r)

# store
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as fh:
    PDF.dumps(fh, doc)
```

`borb` is an open source, pure Python PDF library that creates, modifies and reads PDF documents. You can download it using:

```
pip install borb
```

Alternatively, you can build from source by forking/downloading the [GitHub](https://www.github.com/jorisschellekens/borb) repository.

Comment: Thank you. I just have a question about your code:

what is the difference between : "doc: Document = Document()"
and : "doc = Document()"

What is the function "Decimal(...)" because the program does not find the reference.

Does Borb accept PIL images? Because my images are already uploaded and modified


P.S:
I have the impression that you have forgotten a parenthesis at : 
"with open('output.pdf', 'wb' as fh:"

Comment: Decimal is part of the Python standard library. It allows arbitrary precision decimal numbers. But the import is indeed missing. I fixed that. I also fixed the missing parenthesis. Borb accepts PIL images, URLs (as str) and files (as Path objects)

Comment: The question regarding "what is the difference": this is called "typing". You can make it explicit in Python what you expect the type of a variable to be. Here I made it explicit that I expect this variable to be of type "Document". The advantage to having typed code is that you can have it type-checked. And then you can avoid mistakes like "I am adding a str to a number" or "this function sometimes returns None, but the code that calls it doesn't handle the None case". (Almost) All of borb is typed.